# How do you change the starting point of your plot in R?

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I want to set the starting point of my graph (both in the x- and y-axis) to be zero. I have used the `xlim()` and `ylim()` functions to no avail. I have attached my code below.

```
setwd ("D:/Rcode/Assignment_2") #setting up the working directory
LightGrowth1 <- read.csv ("LightGrowth-1.csv") #reading the file and attaching it to a dataframe
Light <- LightGrowth1$light #attach our light values to a vector in R
Growth <- LightGrowth1$growth #attach our growth values to a vector in R
Labels <- c("Light", "Growth") #create a vector using the labels 
plot (Light, Growth, xlab = "Amount of Light (units)", ylab = "Plant Growth (units)", 
      pch = 16, col= "firebrick", xlim = c(0, max (Light)), ylim = c (0, max (Growth)),
      main = "Plant Growth vs Amount of Light"
       
        )
```

This is what my plot currently looks like:
[image: Plot]

Comment: they are already starting at 0. i am not sure what you want to change. i'd understand if you wanted the x-axis to start at 2 but that is easily done with the `xlim` command

Comment: [This](https://imgur.com/NBPNTEL) is what I wanted my graph to look like (scatterplot version). Based on this, the graph started at a baseline of zero.

Answer (score 1):

Your axes do start at 0, and `xlim` and `ylim` are what you need to change that.

What I think you are referring to is the spacing between the axes and the plot.
There are two extra parameters that allow you to change that, `xaxs` and `yaxs`.

```
plot (x, y, xlim=c(0,10), ylim=c(0,10),
      xaxs="i", yaxs="i")
```

This should do the trick

See the `par` help for more info.

Comment: [This](https://imgur.com/NBPNTEL) is what I wanted my graph to look like (scatterplot version). Based on this, the graph started at a baseline of zero.