# How do I customize where my plot starts in R?

Tags: r

I want to be able to make my plot look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3MrS.png), but it currently looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49Nu5.jpg). Specifically, I want the **bottom left** part of my plot to start at a coordinate of **(0, 0)**. I have attached my R code below. Thanks!

```
plot (Light, Growth, xlab = "Amount of Light (units)", ylab = "Plant Growth (units)", 
      pch = 16, col= "firebrick", xlim = c(0, max (Light)), ylim = c (0, max (Growth)),
      main = "Plant Growth vs Amount of Light"       
        )
```

Comment: Looks like your question was answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63932707/how-do-you-change-the-starting-point-of-your-plot-in-r. Compare the output of `plot (x, y, xlim=c(0,10), ylim=c(0,10), xaxs="i", yaxs="i")` vs `plot (x, y, xlim=c(0,10), ylim=c(0,10))` and you'll see the difference. If you're instead referring to no points on the scatterplot below x = 2 then it might be an issue with the data. Best to give an example in text of your data to get reproducible results.

Comment: Please include your data as a data frame object to make your question reproducible. Use `dput(your_dataframe)` to paste the data into the question. Check out [mre] or [ask] for guidance.